# Buttons not positioning in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Okay, so i have a lot of buttons in my html, but not all of them seem to be positioning. One or two are, but the rest are not. this is the code of one of the ones that is note functioning:

```
<button title="Go through the gate" type="button" onclick="Dungeonmove()" style="top: 900; left: -400; postion: relative; z-index: 1; visibility: show;">Go north</button>
```

And one that is functioning:

```
<button title="Stats" type="button" onclick="lco()" style="top: 0; left: 350; position: relative; z-index: 1; visibility: show;">Check your stats</button>
```

So what's the difference and why aren't some of the buttons positioning? Anyone know?

Comment: Positioning in absolute pixel values is a sign that you're almost certainly doing something very, very wrong...

Comment: ~I know, that was a typo, which i promptly changed

Comment: How did i misunderstand? Did you not mean that i should change "Position: Absolute" To "Position: Relative" Like i did?

Comment: I'm saying that you should not use `position: xxxxx` at all. It is very bad practice to lay everything out pixel by pixel, will quickly break on other browsers/computers, will be a **terrible** pain to debug, and is just generally a terrible idea.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow +1, let's give more examples like different sized screens, or uses the site on mobiles, or requires larger text for accessibility. Having said this, going by the snippet of code, it does look like it's meant to be game controls, which could be thought of as positioned absolutely to overlay like a HUD. Which is all good.

Comment: You would be correct in saying that this looks like code for a game, because it is ^^. Rudimentary, yes, but still :p.

Comment: @setek "Go through the gate" is hardly an HUD ;-) Yes, this would definitely blow up the instant you zoom in/out/change text size.

Comment: Hush :3. Like i said, it's rudimentary. It's like one of those old-style button-click-and-go games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a unit value. The only time you don't have to is for the number `0`.

http://jsfiddle.net/SB9bY/1/

```
<button title="Go through the gate" type="button" onclick="Dungeonmove()" style="top: 900px; left: -400px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; visibility: show;">Go north</button>

<button title="Stats" type="button" onclick="lco()" style="top: 0; left: 350px; position: relative; z-index: 1; visibility: show;">Check your stats</button>
```

Also, check your code for spelling mistakes. You wrote `postion` and not `position`.

Comment: Did you also change the `postion` to `position`?

Comment: ... You are a god :3. It worked! thanks. I can't believe i missed that... even when i looked at your fiddle >.<

Comment: In future, if you are inclined to make spelling mistakes like that, run your code through the [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to help you pick up those easy mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Right of the bat I see the top one is position: absolute and the bottom one is position: relative. What is your goal? You may need to change your approach

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you left "px" off in your top and left declarations

```
<button title="Go through the gate" type="button" onclick="Dungeonmove()" style="top: 900px; left: -400px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; visibility: show;">Go north</button>
```